# How to get window object from sass file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, sass, window

I want to get some value from window object (window.location.host).

How can i do this in my sass file?

```
$assetPath : window.location.host;
```

*window.location should be real data;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location` is a browser object typically accessed using javascript, using such object require you to do this runtime and Sass is not an ecma interpreter.

To access such variables and objects you must generate and store them in a .json at runtime. I believe node.js would be the preferred solution for this unless if you want to post the window.location.host result to a rest-api and expose that as a json to sass

https://www.viget.com/articles/sharing-data-between-sass-and-javascript-with-json

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for the CSS `:target` selector: https://davidwalsh.name/css-target